# how to default to the right version of python on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have both python3.6 and 3.7 and multiple other versions installed. Currently the default is 3.6, yet I need to switch it to 3.7, otherwise it will throw error with some libraries, such as this `https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17237` 'Symbol not found: _PySlice_Unpack'.

I tried a few methods such as
`ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python`.

I also added this line to bash_profile `#export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin`

However when I run `python -V` in terminal it's still python3.6.0. While this looks simple, what's the proper way to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: It would appear the older version is somewhere in your existing `$PATH` before you added the new one. Either remove the old one, or put the new one before it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes I am using virtenv for individual tasks. however, it's still pointed to 3.6 instead of 3.7 for some reasons

Comment: @Grismar Thanks I added this to the top of bash_profile export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin upon closing and reopening terminal, still py3.6.

Comment: can't you use `python3.7` instead of `python` ? BTW: use `which python` to find path to current `python` and then you may try to remove it and put new link in this place - but if some elements in system use `python 3.6` then it can make only problems.

Comment: if you want to add path for 3.7 before other version then add it BEFORE current `$PATH` - `export PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin:$PATH`. And you have to do it in `.bashrc` to have it in all consoles/terminals (if MAC uses `bash` as shell)

Comment: @furas thanks for your answers. I added the export Path line to the top of bashrc and sourced it. a side effect is the previous alias in the bashrc no longer works with 'bad assignment' error. had to remove them. running 'which python' still returns python: aliased to python3 and running 'which python3' returns '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3'

Comment: if you really need `python` as alias to `python3.7` then you have to remove old `python` and create new one using `ln -s`  in the same place. OR you don't remove old `python` and use `ln -s` to create alias in folder `$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin` which is first on `PATH` - so when you try to use `python` then it should use `$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin/python`

Comment: @furas I'm inclined towards the 2nd though don't mind removing py3.6. how could I use ln -s in terminal in mac? got this prompt 'usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]' which is not clear to me. adding the path to 3.7 does not work. Running `export -p` i can see a line starting with 'export -T PATH path=(' still pointing to py3.6

Comment: first use `which python3.7` to find full path for `3.7`. Next you can try `ln -s /full/path/to/python3.7 /$HOME/Library/Python/3.7/bin/python`

Comment: @furas thanks! this solved the problem - new terminal defaults to 3.7. however, the virtenv I created earlier are still in 3.6. Shall I deactivate and create new virtual environment to point to 3.7?

Comment: virtenv was inveted to create environment which never change python version and don't change installed modules - this way environment is safe when you change something outside virtenv (pobably it uses `ln -s` to create `python` inside virtenv which use `python3.6`). If you want to use different python version then you have to create again `virtenv` with different settings and copy code to new virtenv.

Comment: As remeber if you use `python3.7 -m venv ...` then it creates virtenv with `python3.7` assigned to `python`. And if you use `python3.6 -m venv ...` then it creates virtenv with `python3.6` assigned to `python`